# Using double in loops. Possible problem with rounding

Tags: java, rounding

I've got a little question concerning a FOR cycle I've seen today. It looks like this :

```
for (double i = 0.0; i < 1.0; i += 0.1) {  
    for (double j = i; j < 1.0; j += 0.1) {  
        double k = i + j;  
         if ((k % 1) == 0) {  
            System.out.println(i + " + " + j + " = " + k);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

It's supposed to output the sums of two numbers between 0 and 1 (incremented by 0.1) that are equal to a whole number. However, for some reason it does not show the 0.1 + 0.9 = 1.0 sum. My guess is it could be because of incorrect representation of the numbers in double format (i. e. the 0.3 + 0.1 isn't 0.4, but rather something like 0,399999999).

Can anyone possibly confirm this is really the issue and advise how to correct it? Any help appreciated greatly!

Comment: There are zounds of the same questions on SO ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use `int`s - start from `0` till `10` with a step of `1` ? And then `if (k % 10) == 0`

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing something like this you want to use BigDecimal, to avoid rounding problems with floating point types

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing the number and verify your suspicion. If you absolutely must deal with `double` numbers, you can choose to see if the delta to your target value is small enough.

If, on the other hand, you know your step is always 0.1, why not just multiply all the numbers involved by 10? You can just convert to a double by dividing by 10 if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in your guess of representation of floating point numbers, I just take issue with you calling them "incorrect."

Humans talk real numbers in decimal, computers do in binary. In the absolute 0.4 might be very hard to represent in binary, and likewise 0.0101 might be very hard to represent in base 3. You should use BigDecimal if you want to avoid the rounding issues, or use integers and treat them as "number of tenths or hundredths" vs absolute values. This is one way to do currency (Use integers or longs and count cents, vs using floats or decimals and counting dollars)

Comment: Binary numbers are always easily representable in decimal, simply because 2 is a factor of 10. But decimal 0.4 can't be exactly represented in binary, as you say.

Comment: Thanks, point taken. I was (unsuccessfully) trying to show the difference of value representation. Updated.